# Testing Collatz Conjecture by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to Python, so please don't mock at me if I asked a silly question. I tried to test the Collatz Conjecture by using Python, and I wrote several lines of code as following:

```
a = 1

while True:
    i = a
    while i != 1:
        if i%2 == 0:
            i = i/2
        if i%2 != 0:
            i = 3*i + 1
    print(a, 'will eventually fall to 1')
    a = a + 1
```

The result I expected to get were something like:

1 will eventually fall to 1

2 will eventually fall to 1

3 will eventually fall to 1

4 will eventually fall to 1

5 will eventually fall to 1

...

I expected the program would continue to produce output forever until I interrupted it manually. However, when I ran my code, I only got one line of output:

1 will eventually fall to 1

What is wrong with my code? I cannot figure the mistake out, thank you so much if you can correct me.

Comment: What is the value of `i` in the first iteration of the loop, and how will that effect the inner `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if`s test `i` twice. The second time after it has been halved (and it might become `1`) you then test whether it is odd, which it is and perform `3*i + 1` and then its not `1` anymore.

You need an `if/else` at that point:

```py
a = 1

while True:
    i = a
    while i != 1:
        if i%2 == 0:
            i = i/2
        else:
            i = 3*i + 1
    print(a, 'will eventually fall to 1')
    a = a + 1
```

Output as expected.